# Any Design Pattern for this use case

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a class that has certain fields say a Profile Class. Fields are Name, Designation, Work-place, Phone number etc. Now it might happen that in future we add some field to these classes. One method for sure is to manually add the fields and add the getter and setters for it. But is there a design pattern or way so that we have a provision to add new fields to our java class so that when we create an object we have that field added.

Comment: There are dozens of potential ways you could approach this. However it depends on plenty of things, such as how often would you expect to have fields added etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is there a design pattern or way so that we have a provision to
>   add new fields to our java class so that when we create an object we
>   have that field added.

Well if you add any field then you have to modify your class. There is no other way

Design patterns are solutions to general problems that software developers faced during software development. Design patterns are to make design more maintainable but it does not mean you don't make any modifications